# laravel 5 format datetime

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an array that return the following date time:

```
$item['created_at'] => "2015-10-28 19:18:44"
```

And I need this outuput:

```
"2016-08-10T13:15:00.000+10:00"
```

Exist any function to convert this date?

Comment: Does it actually return a string like that, or does it return a Carbon/DateTime object?

Comment: Well, since laravel is by default shipped with [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), you could use that. Even if it's a string or a Carbon/DateTime object.

Comment: But your'e not simply reformatting a date to get from `2015-10-28 19:18:44` to `2016-08-10T13:15:00.000+10:00`.... how many days/months/years/hours/minutes/seconds are you adjusting it by? And what's the rule for that change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$dt = new \DateTime('2015-10-28 19:18:44', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
dd($dt->format('c')); // string '2015-10-28T19:18:44+00:00' (length=25)
```

Alternatively take a look at [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/carbon)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel's accessors to get "reformatted" `created_at`.

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    //Since Laravel uses Carbon you can do.
    return $value->format('c');
}
```

This way anytime you do something like `$model->created_at` it will return modified `created_at`.

If you want to change datetime format for `created_at` in your database as well, you can use mutators.

More information you can find on the [Laravel's docs page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).

Comment: I'd be careful with an accessor on Laravel's magic column names like ID, created/updated/deleted etc.. Better to give this a different name - something like `getFormattedCreatedAtAttribute` and `formatted_created_at`.

Comment: @ceejayoz What might happen?

Comment: I'm gonna take a wild guess here and assume that is uses some sort of magic method to work with that value. Again I'm going to assume that words like create/update/etc are "reserved"(not per-se, but get it). And since debugging magic methods is the equivalent of killing yourself with a fork, better to avoid it.

Comment: That depends on the developer and his level of organization and understanding of the matter and has nothing to do with the language/framework. So I'd prefer not to agree with your arguments. :)